# How can I see all my repositories on github which are NOT in an organisation?

Tags: github, repository

I am cleaning my GitHub repositories which are not in an organisatgion, i.e. moving them to appropriate organisations, archiving them, etc.

My question: How can I easily see which repositories are **not** in an organisation (the organisations, I will tackle later)?

Answer (score 0):

Ups - just realized, that the repos I see when looking at my repos, are my repos, and not an organization's repos - makes sense somehow…